# Refresh token in outlook web addin

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing Outlook Web Add-in. I am using REST API calls for moving a message from one folder to another folder using `Accesstoken`.

```js
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true },
    function (result) {
        if (result.status === "succeeded") {
            var accessToken = result.value;

            // Use the access token
            MoveMailItem(accessToken);
        } else {
            // Handle the error
        }
    });
```

Is anyway to refresh this token so that I will call again this method?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method for refreshing the token, you simply request a new one after the token expires (they have a 5 minute lifetime).

Refresh tokens are used to avoid having a user need to re-enter their credentials. Since this isn't part of the `getCallbackTokenAsync` workflow, there be any benefit in refreshing a token vs retrieving a new one.

Comment: @Shyam, as @Marc mentioned, there's no method for refreshing the token. Is there a reason why you want to avoid calling `getCallbackTokenAsync`? Does it "break" the `MoveMailItem` call you have in your code?

Answer (score 0):

getCallbackTokenAsync() API would always return a token that has a validity of 5 min. So if the validity is over the add-in will have to call this API again to get a new token.

If the Add-in implements SSO flow then the add-in can get an access and refresh token as part of the first login. The add-in can use the refresh token to get a new token everytime the validity is over. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code